# Cloudwatch custom event triggered instantly even after passing schedule time AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to use aws cloudwatch events for task scheduling in Node js, So , I created a cloudwatch event rule for this, Then I added a lambda function as a target. I am using event patterns to create a cloudwatch event rule here instead of scheduled expression. Now I am trying to add events to it at a scheduled time , but the event triggers instantly as soon as a put a event on cloudwatch. I don't know why this is happening, I researched a lot but didn't find anything relevant.

I used these official docs as reference :- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudWatchEvents.html#putEvents-property
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/cloudwatch-examples-sending-events.html

I am new to AWS , please help me here.

This is the code performing the above mentioned action.

```
var params = {
        Name: 'DEMO_EVENT',
        RoleArn: 'iamroleArn',
        EventPattern: JSON.stringify({
            source: ['myapp.events'],
        }),
        State: 'ENABLED'
      };
      
      cwevents.putRule(params, function(err, rule) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error", err);
        } else {
          console.log("Success", rule.RuleArn);
          var params = {
            Rule: 'DEMO_EVENT',
            Targets: [
              {
                Arn: 'lambda function arn',
                Id: "default"
              }
            ]
          };
          
          cwevents.putTargets(params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
              console.log("Error", err);
            } else {
              console.log("Success", data);
              var params = {
                Entries: [
                  {
                    Detail: JSON.stringify({
                      "meetingNo": "82565852285"
                    }),
                    DetailType: 'meeting',
                    Resources: [
                        rule.RuleArn
                    ],
                    Source: 'myapp.events',
                    Time: new Date("2022-01-07T08:00:00Z"), // here I am sending the schedule time in utc
                  }
                ]
              };
              
              cwevents.putEvents(params, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                  console.log("Error", err);
                } else {
                  console.log("Success", data.Entries);
                }
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour.  `PutEvents` puts events immediately.  The `Time` parameter is not a scheduling mechanism, but rather an option for callers to provide a timestamp other than the time of the `PutEvents` call.

EventBridge (formerly CloudWatch Events) [does have support for cron expressions and rate expressions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html), with the [PutRule Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/clients/client-eventbridge/classes/putrulecommand.html).

##### Scheduled rules generate events at set, periodic intervals

EventBridge [PutRule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/example_eventbridge_PutRule_section.html) scheduling works with *regular recurring schedules*.  For instance, a rule with a `0/15 * * * ? *` [cron expression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-create-rule-schedule.html#eb-cron-expressions) will generate an event with a generic payload 4x per hour every day for as long as the rule is enabled.

##### Alternative for arbitrary scheduling of payload delivery

If you are looking to raise events with custom detail at arbitrary times (e.g. *do something with this order record in 5 days*; or *send an event on each user's birthday*), then scheduled EventBridge rules are not sufficient.  For such "deferred delivery" scenarios, you could use a scheduled event rule to periodically poll a data store for deliveries that are due.  A `PollingLambda`, say, could in turn raise a custom event with `{type:"HappyBirthday", name:"Zaphod", email:...}` payload for each approaching birthday, which a second rule would send to a `SendBirthdayGreetingLambda`.

Comment: Great advice @fedonev, but Putrule has a limitation that is , we can have only 300 rules at a time, any solution for this? Due to this limitation, I thought that I can create a single rule and add multiple events to it.

Comment: A [rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-rules.html) either (A) sends an event to a target on a schedule (_run my lambda every Tuesday at 10.00_) or (B) forwards an event to a target when an incoming event matches the rule's pattern (_run Lambda B if an event is received from Lambda A with a `Status` of `New Order`_).  In scenario (A), EventBridge itself raises the event.  In (B), EventBridge acts upon incoming events put to it by other AWS services or `PutEvents`.

Comment: I'm not sure what problem you are actually trying to solve.  Perhaps edit your post to add an example.

Comment: I got the solution for adding more cloudwatch events rules to my account , but still thanks for resolving this events confusion related to event pattern. This thing is not clearly mentioned in docs.

Comment: I would like to ask one more thing before marking this answer as correct, Is there a way to have more than one scheduled events in a single cloudwatch rule?

Comment: Short answer: yes, of course.  I added to my answer what EventBridge means by "scheduled event".  Without a specific use case example, though, I had to guess what you mean by it.